# Finding original codd rules

Tags: sql, database, rdbms

I've been cruising the web on the subject of Codd's 12 rules for a long time now. I've read what amounts to about 50 articles and hundreds of posts on the subject. If you compare the rules from all those, you find large disparities in what is said so I don't trust any of them to be correct.Unfortunately, Mr. Codd is no longer in the land of the living (may his soul rest in peace).
Could anyone point me to text containing the original 12 rules by EF Codd?

Comment: *I swear to rely on the key, the whole key, and nothing but the key, so help me Codd* :-)

Comment: [Have you checked Wikipedia?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codd%27s_12_rules)

Comment: well ; on wiki they have mentioned 13 rules instead of 12. o.O